Copying overlapping objects with auto-generated operator =
In the following program, union U has active member of type A, which is copied using auto-generated operator = into another member of type B, having A as subobject:
#include <iostream>

struct A { char c[7]; };

struct X { char x; };

struct B : X, A {
    using A::operator=;
};

int main() {
    union U {
        A a{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        B b;
    } u;
    
    //#1
    u.b = u.a;

    //#2
    //u.b = A( u.a );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i )
        std::cout << (int)u.b.c[i];
}

I would like to get 0123456 output, but actual compilers without optimization produce different output.

MSVC: 0000000
Clang: 0123355
GCC and EDG: 0122356

Question #1: Is it because the program has undefined behavior due to simultaneous access to both active and inactive members of the union during copying?
If instead of u.b = u.a;, I first create a temporary copy, and assign it using u.b = A( u.a );, then the results of MSVC and Clang become expected 0123456, but GCC and EDG insist on the same 0122356. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dxfzEM5eM
Question #2: Is the program well-formed now, and unexpected result is due to bugs in the implementations?

Evaluation order for E1 @= E2 is guaranteed since C++17, E2 happens before E1. For previous version, there are no guarantee order, so potentially UB: evaluate u.b before ends lifetime of u.a.

A a = u.a; u.b = u.a; should produce expected result.

Turning the function in constexpr allows to detect some UBs, and indeed, clang and msvc report an issue Demo

@Jarod42 This demo shows a few interesting cases.  I replaced char x with some stateless spacers to get a similar behavior, but avoid uninitialized data in the constexpr branch.  If you add/remove the cast, add/remove constexpr on the foo function, and add/remove constexpr on the result in main, you get: clang thinks (A) cast in assignment is needed for it to be constexpr, gcc doesn't, and gcc writes the "correct" code in a constexpr case and "bad" code in the non-constexpr case.  The (A) cast doesn't change gcc's "bad" code.

@Jarod42, thanks! Actually only Clang rejects constexpr version of this program. And MSVC error was due to return from constexpr function B with uninitialized x field. After returning only copied part, MSVC is fine with the code

@Fedor Try out version 5 in my demo - we clang believes there is illegal operations occuring in u.b=u.a.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont, thanks. Your version 5 shows that option #1 is not valid in constant expression, and probably answers the question #1. And version 7 is already accepted in Clang. Does it mean that GCC and EDG present same bug in question #2?
